# Change the text in a field with a VBA function

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm currently working on a database in Access which has a table (`Pro_Cons`) who compares the pros and cons of different product-types. This table has 3 columns; Type (`Product_type`), Pros (`Pro`) and Cons.
For each of product-type I created a form which includes the pro- and the cons-field of the according type out of this table.
For adding new text to this fields I'm creating a VBA-function which is triggered by a button-click.

Because nothing worked as supposed to, I created the following function, which should only replace the `Pro` -field of the product `type1` to `change1`.

Access doesnt throw an error, but nothing changes in the table.

Has someone an idea whats happening here?

```
Sub Change_Pos_Inf()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSensortyp As String
Dim strNew As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

strProduct_type = "type1"
strNew = "change1"
strSQL = "SELECT Pro FROM Pro_Cons WHERE Product_type='strProduct_type';"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rst

   If .RecordCount > 0 Then

    .MoveFirst

    .Edit

    !Pro.Value = strNew

    .Update

   End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First, "WHERE Product_type='strProduct_type';" will never return any rows -- unless you really have that value in the field.  It should be: "WHERE Product_type=' " & strProduct_type & "';" Or, put a breakpoint on '!Pro.Value = strNew'  That will show if you ever execute that code.  Also, close your recordset!

Comment: thx for the fast reply! It seems like the the functions stops at `.RecordCount`. If I remove the If-loop, I get error 3021

Comment: I believe RecordCount only gets set if you first do a .MoveLast. I am going on memory, so don't hold me to that. :-)

Comment: When I include `.MoveLast` I get Error 3021 too...

Comment: In debug mode, can you put a breakpoint on the OpenReordset statement, and while it is paused, in the immediate window, type ? strSQL, and then let us know what the result is?

Comment: Did you correct the problem with your 'WHERE' clause that I mentioned? And, yes @DanielG, the recordcount is -1 until you do a MoveLast (and of course don't forget the .MoveFirst afterwards).  The 3021 error is "NO RECORD FOUND" --- which is exactly as I suspect due to the 'WHERE' clause.

Comment: Yeah, I changed both

Answer (score 1):

I think your literal should be changed to reference a form control:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Pro FROM Pro_Cons WHERE Product_type='strProduct_type';"
```

Changes to:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Pro FROM Pro_Cons WHERE Product_type='" & Me!strProduct_type & 
"'";
```

Comment: How can I get the right field with `Me!strProduct_type` when the field in the form doesnt include this term? This throws an error "wrong usage of 'Me'" btw

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code. It corrects your WHERE clause:

```
Sub Change_Pos_Inf()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSensortyp As String
Dim strNew As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

strProduct_type = "type1"
strNew = "change1"
strSQL = "SELECT Pro FROM Pro_Cons WHERE Product_type= '" & strProduct_type & "';"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rst

   If Not rst.EOF Then

    .Edit
        !Pro.Value = strNew
    .Update
   Else
       MsgBox "No Record found!!"
   End If
End With
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thx! But can you explain me why this code doesnt work anymore when I remove the If-loop? It should make a difference because it chances the text if the condition is NOT fulfilled, or?

Comment: Your original question was why the code did not update a record. That was because you had an incorrect 'WHERE' clause - nothing to do with the 'IF' statement. The 'IF' can be removed, but only if you are 100% certain you never try to find a record that doesn't exist.

Comment: You're totally right, sorry. I copied your code and removed the loop, everything works as supposed to. I dont see the difference compared to my corrected code, but there seems to be one :D

Comment: Since I can't see your 'corrected code', the 'difference' that made it work is the WHERE clause in your SQL statement. The IF doesn't make any difference in my, or your, code. Note that I chose to check 'rst.EOF' instead of what your original code had -- but either would work (AS LONG AS the WHERE was corrected)